# Python - Removing \n when using default split()?

Tags: python

I'm working on strings where I'm taking input from the command line. For example, with this input:

```
format driveName "datahere"
```

when I go string.split(), it comes out as:

```
>>> input.split()
['format, 'driveName', '"datahere"']
```

which is what I want.

However, when I specify it to be string.split(" ", 2), I get:

```
>>> input.split(' ', 2)
['format\n, 'driveName\n', '"datahere"']
```

Does anyone know why and how I can resolve this? I thought it could be because I'm creating it on Windows and running on Unix, but the same problem occurs when I use nano in unix.

The third argument (data) could contain newlines, so I'm cautious not to use a sweeping newline remover.

Comment: Note that your input does *not* replicate the problem, because it *doesn't* contain any newlines. How do you fetch input? There may be a more appropriate solution. Also, `input` is a builtin function, not a string - please specify how you've overwritten it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `None` to get the default whitespace splitting behaviour with a limit:

```
input.split(None, 2)
```

This leaves the whitespace at the *end* of `input()` untouched.

Or you could strip the values afterwards; this removes whitespace from the start and end, not the middle, of each resulting string, just like `input.split()` would:

```
[v.strip() for v in input.split(' ', 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Default separator in `split()` is all whitespace which includes newlines `\n` and spaces.

Here is what the [docs on split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) say:

```
str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])

If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is 
applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single 
separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start 
or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.
```

When you define a new `sep` it only uses that separator to `split` the strings.

Answer (score 0):

The default `str.split` targets a number of "whitespace characters", including also tabs and others. If you do `str.split(' ')`, you tell it to split *only* on `' '` (a space). You can get the default behavior by specifying `None`, as in `str.split(None, 2)`.

There may be a better way of doing this, depending on what your actual use-case is (your example does not replicate the problem...). As your example output implies newlines as separators, you should consider splitting on them explicitly.

```
inp = """
format
driveName
datahere
datathere
"""
inp.strip().split('\n', 2)
# ['format', 'driveName', 'datahere\ndatathere']
```

This allows you to have spaces (and tabs etc) in the first and second item as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes sense now!